# Javascript split string with regex and then join it

Tags: javascript, regex, split

Hey I want a function that can split a string for example `"(12/x+3)*heyo"` which i could edit each number, letter and word by itself and then return the edited version. So far i got this (which not work as intended):

```
function calculate(input){
    var vars = input.split(/[+-/*()]/);
    var operations = input.split(/[^+-/*()]/);
    var output = "";

    vars = vars.map(x=>{
        return x+"1";
    });

    for(var i=0; i<operations.length; i++){
        output += operations[i]+""+((vars[i])?vars[i]:"");
    }
    return output;
}
```

For example: `(12/x+3)*heyo` returns: `(1121/x1+31)*1heyo1` but should return `(121/x1+31)*heyo1`

Comment: could you use `.replace` with a regex instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `regex` and `replace` method for this task:

```js
var s = "(12/x+3)*heyo";

console.log(
  s.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g, "$1" + 1)
)
```

Depending what characters you want to match, you may want `/([^-+/*()]+)/g` as the pattern:

```js
var s = "(12/x+3)*heyo";

console.log(
  s.replace(/([^-+/*()]+)/g, "$1" + 1)
)
```

Comment: Yes, why didn't I think about replace..? But I'm not sure how the replace works with regex, got any links?

Comment: You can see some examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Switching_words_in_a_string).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the vars array is populated with empty results, which are adding "1" inadvertently.  I slightly modified your arrow function to check x for a value.

```
vars = vars.map(x=>{
    if (x) {
       return x+"1";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be simplified a bit (but `\w` matches underscore too `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) :

```js
console.log( '(12/x+3)*heyo'.replace(/\w+/g, '$&1') )

console.log( '(12/x+3)*heyo'.replace(/\w+/g, m => m + 1) )
```